# group by year of birth

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I've a table sales

```
idcustomer  year of birth   amount  salesdate
112 1970    200 12/02/2022
12  1980    400 12/03/2012
122 1990    600 12/04/2012
300 1977    20  12/06/2012
500 1996    250 12/04/2012
```

I need to see how different agegroups perform, how much is sales per month and year,  Grouped in year of birth in 5 years, like 1980-1984, 1985-1989. I'd like agegroup to be dynamically created as new column in powerquery for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly clear what you want.

I assumed you always wanted your groupings to start on a multiple of five.

- create a list of groupings based on the earliest date of birth rounded down to the nearest multiple of five.
- Add a column which has the start year of the grouping
- Add another column which takes that year and creates the text that you want for your grouping

***Original data***
[image]

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table24"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"idcustomer", Int64.Type}, {"year of birth", Int64.Type}, 
        {"amount", Int64.Type}, {"salesdate", type date}}),

//add grouping column depending on min/max year of birth

    //round firstYear down to a multiple of 5
    firstYear =Number.IntegerDivide(List.Min(#"Changed Type"[year of birth]),5)*5,
    lastYear = List.Max(#"Changed Type"[year of birth]),

    //create list of groupings
    groupings = List.Numbers(firstYear, Number.IntegerDivide(lastYear-firstYear,5)+1,5),

    //group for first year selected from the list
    #"First Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","firstYear",
        each List.Last(List.Select(groupings, (li)=> li <= [year of birth])), Int64.Type),

    //grouping column added as text
    #"Add Grouping Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"First Year","Grouper", 
        each Text.From([firstYear]) & "-" & Text.From([firstYear]+4),type text),

    //remove first year column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Grouping Column",{"firstYear"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***Results***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly described, but sample code below for powerquery sets up the columns for year, month, and bucket. You can then group on bucket column and one of the other columns to do whatever math you want

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"idcustomer", Int64.Type}, {"year of birth", Int64.Type}, {"amount", Int64.Type}, {"salesdate", type date}}),

// add columns for year, month and year/month
// you could probably do some math on the year instead, but too lazy to figure it out

#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "SalesYear", each Date.Year([salesdate])),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "SalesMonth", each Date.Month([salesdate])),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "MonthYear", each #date(Date.Year([salesdate]),Date.Month([salesdate]),1)),

// generate list of buckets from 1940 through 2050, every 5 years
List = Table.FromList(List.Transform(List.Generate(() => 1940, each _ < 2050, each _ + 5), each Text.From(_)), null, {"Bucket"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(List, "Year", each {Number.From([Bucket]) .. Number.From([Bucket])+4 }),
#"Expanded Year" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Year"),

 // add bucket column
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom3", {"year of birth"}, #"Expanded Year", {"Year"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Bucket"}, {"Bucket"})
in #"Expanded Table2"
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to change bucket to get like range 1980-1984, 1985-1989 please ?

Comment: edited the +4 to +5